# Calling Property Methods from the e.PropertyName property

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

```
void TheSettings_PropertyChanged(object sender, 
             System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[StorageSettings]  
                                              as Dictionary<string, string>;

    settings[e.PropertyName]= //call the method that has the same property 
                              //   name to get what the value is

    LoadData();
}
```

Here is What I am trying to do. This is for a Windows Phone 7 series App. I am trying to determine what values got changed when the user changes the settings on the settings page and just save that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dynamically call properties, use Reflection.
This example gets a value: http://www.vcskicks.com/properties.php